# Cannot Install package MICE in R

Tags: r

I have an issue to install MICE package. I got an error message:

[image]

I downloaded Rtools, but the problem still remains. Do you know how to deal with it? Thank you

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: I don't see an error. The first bit is a *warning*, but do you not have `library(mice)` available after this command?

Comment: Also, installing Rtools is one thing ... does R know that it is installed? If you happen to have `pkgbuild` (`packageVersion("pkgbuild")`) installed, you can use these to see if something is found: `pkgbuild::has_build_tools()` (bool), `pkgbuild::rtools_path()` (character, its path). If false and/or empty, then ... your installation of Rtools is *incomplete*.

Comment: Sorry for posting the image here. So I can see MICE in my available packages. However,  when we start to use MICE function, the error message - cannot find function mice. I am very confused.

Comment: Have you tried `library(mice)`?

Comment: Then I download Rtools in my laptop, the warning still remains. I check it using pkgbuild::rtools_path(), I see the loading path for tools C:\\rtools40/usr/bin. How does R recognize that it is installed?

Comment: Yes, I use library(mice), It shows me another error: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required. Do I need to load rlang?

Comment: Version errors like that are rarely spurious: if it says it needs 0.4.7 and has 0.4.6, then *yes*, you should update. That does suggest that there is more to the "warning" message you have included above.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the documentation, I realize that I have to install Rtools to download the packages. I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2IPWVXaUuU is very useful to explain how to download Rtools and make it recognizable in R.